# accessing redux store from inside a function caused non persisted state RTK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

My persisted state was working correctly but after accessing store from a function to do some tests with preloaded state parameter it can't be persisted. It's rehydrated at first render but nothing accessed or persisted to the browser. I think when state is updated nothing causes rerender from the store, but how to solve it?

store

```js
export default function setupStore (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    preloadedState,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => 
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck:  {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        }
      }).concat(logger),
  })
  return store
}

export const persistor = persistStore(setupStore())
```

//root reducer

```
export const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['dealerStoreReducer'],//soon later,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 ,
  // version: 1,
}
  
export const dealerStorePersistConfig = {
  key: 'dealerStore',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['cartItems','adminStore'],
  // version: 1,
  //blacklist: ['dealerStoreReducer'],//soon later,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 ,
}

export type DealerStoreReducer = initialStatedealerStore & PersistPartial;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  labels: labelsReducer,
  dealers: dealersReducer,
  user: usersReducer,
  orders: ordersReducer,
  orderItems: orderItemsReducer,
  dealerStore: persistReducer<initialStatedealerStore, any>(dealerStorePersistConfig, dealerStoreReducer),
})

export type RootReducer = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export const persistedReducer = persistReducer<RootReducer >(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer) 

export default rootReducer
```

index

```
root.render(
  <Provider store={setupStore()}>
    <BarsContextProvider>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </BarsContextProvider>,
  </Provider>,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you are doing with any *specific* store instance, but according to the code you've shown you've instantiated ***at least*** two different store objects. One when creating the `persistor` and the other when passing a store to the `react-redux` `Provider` component.

store.js

```js
export default function setupStore (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    preloadedState,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => 
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck:  {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
        }
      }).concat(logger),
  });
  return store;
}

export const persistor = persistStore(setupStore()); // <-- store instance #1
```

index.js

```
root.render(
  <Provider store={setupStore()}> // <-- store instance #2
    <BarsContextProvider>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </BarsContextProvider>,
  </Provider>,
);
```

To resolve you'll want to instantiate only a single store instance to be used across the app.

You can either export the `setupStore` function for use in testing/etc, and then also an instantiated `store` and `persistor`:

store.js

```js
export default function setupStore (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    preloadedState,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => 
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck:  {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
        }
      }).concat(logger),
  });
  return store;
}

export const store = setupStore(); // <-- store instance

export const persistor = persistStore(store); // <-- store instance passed in
```

index.js

```
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}> // <-- same store instance
    <BarsContextProvider>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}> // <-- also used here
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </BarsContextProvider>,
  </Provider>,
);
```

Or you can just export the `setupStore` utility and instantiate the store and persistor in the `index.js` file.

store.js

```js
export default function setupStore (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    preloadedState,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => 
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck:  {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
        }
      }).concat(logger),
  });
  return store;
}
```

index.js

```
const store = setupStore(); // <-- instantiate store
const persistor = persistStore(store); // <-- pass store instance

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}> // <-- same store instance
    <BarsContextProvider>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}> // <-- also used here
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </BarsContextProvider>,
  </Provider>,
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot @DrewReese . I really don't  know how I missed that I have two instances.